# how to deploy dapps into production (mainnetwork)

Tags: blockchain

i'm newbee as a blockchain developer.I have deployed smart contract into ethereum test network.as part of next step i want to know what are the steps invovled in deploying blockchain at production level.

this is my smartcontract code and i tried to deploy into my own private network with muitple nodes.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract  {

  mapping(address => uint) public answers;
  string question;
  address asker;
  uint trues;
  uint falses;

  /// __init__
  function Questions(string _question) public {
    asker = msg.sender;
    question = _question;
  }

  function answerQuestion (bool _answer) public {
    if (answers[msg.sender] == 0 && _answer) { 
      answers[msg.sender] = 1; //they vote true
      trues += 1;
    }
    else if (answers[msg.sender] == 0 && !_answer) {
      answers[msg.sender] = 2; //falsity
      falses += 1;
    }
    else if (answers[msg.sender] == 2 && _answer) { // false switching to true
      answers[msg.sender] = 1; //true
      trues += 1;
      falses -= 1;
    }
    else if (answers[msg.sender] == 1 && !_answer) { // true switching to false
      answers[msg.sender] = 2; //falsity
      trues -= 1;
      falses += 1;
    }
  }

  function getQuestion() public constant returns (string, uint, uint, uint) {
    return (question, trues, falses, answers[msg.sender]);
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi gowri, welcome to StackExchange! Can you provide us more details, i.e. post your contract and describe your deployment tools?

Answer (score 2):

There's no big differences. You only need to connect to a mainnet endpoint to deploy your smart contract instead of testnet endpoint and of course you need to have ETH balance in your account to pay the tnx fee. And notice that the gas limit to deploy smart contract is high so be careful and testing thoroughly on the testnet first, otherwise you have to pay high fee for nothing if your contract is not at production level.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i got few other doubts like what is the system requirments and how many nodes can be connected to single private blockchain?